# How can one use motility testing as a practically reliable test for organisms identification in bacteriology?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, locomotion

### Background information:

The motility test is used to determine whether an organism is motile or non-motile. There are three types of bacterial motility *****:

1. Active movement: true motility that we are testing
2. Passive movement: Drifting of the organisms in the same direction along the convectional current in the fluid
3. Brownian movement: It is an oscillatory movement about a nearly fixed point possessed by all small bodies suspended in fluid and due to irregularities in their bombardments by molecules of water.

***** Sastry, A. S., & Bhat, S. K. (2017). Essentials of Practical Microbiology. JP Medical Ltd.

### Question:

How can one use motility testing as a practically reliable test for organisms identification in bacteriology?

In other words, how to differentiate true motility from passive and Brownian movements?

Specifically, i'm screening for non motile bacteria.